# How to Install/Configure Oracle Instant Client on Ubuntu

Tags: oracle, ubuntu

Installing the Oracle Instant Client on Ubuntu/Debian based systems is awkward since Oracle is RPM centric regarding its Linux support.

What's the best way to easily install and configure the Instant Client on Ubuntu?

Comment: Note - I had to download the rpm: oracle-instantclient11.2-devel-11.2.0.3.0-1.x86_64.rpm by hand to get this to work.
Thanks!

Comment: @EdMurray Thanks for that note Ed.  I've made updates to the script and to address that issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated Per Feedback**
I never really found a good answer to this that didn't involve a lot of manual steps, so I made a solution.

You can download a script from my oracle_instant_client_for_ubuntu [GitHub repo](https://github.com/eikonomega/oracle_instant_client_for_ubuntu_64bit) which will convert Oracle rpms into Ubuntu compatible packages and then install them for you.

It now supports multiple versions of the instant client.  Feel free to log issues via GitHub.

**Currently, this project only supports 64-bit systems.**

Comment: @Eikonomega-->This worked perfectly!!! Your [oracle_client](https://github.com/eikonomega/oracle_instant_client_for_ubuntu_64bit)!I installed the oracle_instant_client_for_ubuntu and tested out on my Ubuntu 12.10 desktop and worked perfectly! I used the oracle instant client to connect to the Oracle Database 11.2.3 from the tool-->Oracle SQL Developer (3.2). Worked Perfectly!! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @sven I'm glad to here that it worked for you.  Did you happen to try and connect to the database from SQL Developer prior to using the tool?

Comment: eikonomega's repo is broken and he isn't accepting pull requests to fix it.  Use this fork instead: https://github.com/yokotoka/oracle_instant_client_for_ubuntu_64bit

Comment: @BinaryPhile As a really strange coincidence, I'm just happening to update the repo now.  I've incorporated existed pull requests and will be adding on some new functionality tonight.

Comment: The repo readme now states that this solution no longer works

Answer (score 0):

It took me about two hours to install this instant client. Then I figured out that there is a great graphical client available for Oracle DB, which would suit my needs better then oracle instant client. In case you are interested, here is info on how to install it on Ubuntu:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/458554/how-to-install-sql-developer-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

Another solution referenced a few github repos that automated it, but the most recent one was not updated for python3, and it didn't run anymore. I updated it and fixed it, but I cannot comment on that one as I don't have the reputation to support it.

https://github.com/TimothyMalahy/oracle_instant_client_for_ubuntu_64bit

After I downloaded that, CD'd into the archive and followed the instructions

ran

```
sudo python3 system_setup.py
```

or if you were on a virtual environment enabled

```
sudo python system_setup.py
```