# Installation of Oracle Instant Client on an Ubuntu 64 machine

Tags: oracle, client

I would like to install Oracle Instant Client on a Ubuntu 64 bit machine.

Following [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Oracle%20Instant%20Client), I have installed the rpm packages basic, development and sqlplus using alien.

Then:

```
sqlplus  username/password@//dbhost:1521/SID
sqlplus: command not found

export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64
ls $ORACLE_HOME
bin  lib

sqlplus
sqlplus: command not found
```

I have tried the python script in [this link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36609/how-to-install-configure-oracle-instant-client-on-ubuntu), but this did not work. It conflicts with the installed 12.1 packages as it tries to install 11.2.

Answer (score 9):

Easily solved:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Stick those lines in your `~/.bash_profile` if you want them to persist for a given user, or in `/etc/bashrc` to persist for all users.

Comment: Thanks Phil - it worked. Stuck it into ~/.bashrc. [/etc contained only bash.bashrc].

Comment: +1 for helping users to use oracle db even on distributions which are considered "unsupported" by the company.

Comment: @Peter -1 for appearing to have an attitude problem towards me

Comment: @Phil Is it possible for me to contact you privately?